# Manipulate String to Dictionary and viceversa

Tags: python

Through a http Post using httplib2 I obtain some statistics from a network resource :

```
resp, content = http.request(statistics_url,
            method='POST',
            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'charset':'UTF-8','Connection':'keep-alive','Host':'theHost'},
            body=json_body)
```

The "`resp`" reveals that I receive back "`{'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'...`"

Checking the type of the `content` obj : `type(content)` returns `str`

and the format of the `content` object is :

```
{ 
  "key" : "string value"
   ............
   "key" : int value
}
```

Since I want to augment this with some other data I turn this into a Json object, append to it the data I need and then try to do a string out of it again ( since I need to pass it further)

```
jdata = json.loads(s)
jdata['ip_address']="some ip address"

v1 = json.dumps(jdata)
v2 = ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(jdata))
v3 = ast.literal_eval(pprint.pformat(jdata)
```

None of `v1,v2,v3` returns the dictionary in the same format as original. I obtain either 
formats like `{'key' : 'value'} or {u'key' : u'value'}` which leads to undesired results then passing this information down to other entities.

The question is how to obtain the same format as described above ?

Comment: How exactly does the "new" format differ from the "old" format?

Comment: The characters that wrap the key/value pair is ' instead of ". This seems not to work for me.

Comment: So then why not reencode as JSON?

Comment: I would if I knew about it .Forgot to mention, I just began learning python .

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `indent` named parameter to a number to get pretty-printed results. The `v1` version is the way to go:

```
import json

s = """
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": 5
}
"""

jdata = json.loads(s)
jdata['ip_address']="1.2.3.4"

v1 = json.dumps(jdata, indent=2)
print(v1)

""" Prints
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": 5,
  "ip_address": "1.2.3.4"
}
"""
```